# My loop in java is not working. Can anyone see why?

Tags: java, loops

I have a lab in programming due soon. My program stops after asking for inputs after it asks for one. I cannot see what I did wrong. Can anyone see the problem?

```
public static double dReadInputs(int numberOfInputs)        //this accepts and fills an array with grade inputs
{
    int t = 0;
    double[] inputs = new double[numberOfInputs];
    while (t < numberOfInputs)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 10 grade values one at a time: ");
        inputs[10] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        t++;
    }
    return inputs[10];
```

Comment: I'm just assuming that numberOfInputs is 10 and you are trying to assign inputs[10] which would be an error because inputs[] would only have index 0-9

Comment: Did you get any exception? Did you enter any grade (before closing the dialog)? Why do you only use `inputs[10]`? How about the other ones? Is `numberOfInputs` big enough to support `inputs[10]` (i.e. at least 11)?

Comment: Shoudn't you be using `inputs[t]`? Also, why are you building an array if you want to return one value?

Comment: Like @ElliottFrisch said, use inputs[t] and change your while to while(t < numberOfInputs-1.

Comment: First of all inputs[10] should be inputs[t] and increment the t

Comment: I'm trying to have the program take in 10 grade values in an array that I can average them together later.

Answer (score 1):

The index 10 in `inputs[10]` throws an exception because it might be greater than the size of the `inputs` variable.

This might work in your case:

```
inputs[t] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double[] dReadInputs(int numberOfInputs)        //this accepts     and fills an array with grade inputs
{
    int t = 0;
    double[] inputs = new double[numberOfInputs];
    while (t < numberOfInputs)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter "+numberOfInputs+"grade values one at a time: ");
        inputs[t] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        t++;
    }
    return inputs;
}
```

Basically, you want to get all the inputs so you want to return a double array instead of just a single double. Also, make sure you use a counter (or even better yet create a for loop) so you update the respective double in the double array.

What's happening is that you're always writing to the 11th item in the array when you only have an array of size 10, so it's giving an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Thanks! It's been changed

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding from your question description. You want the JOptionPane to show 10 times and each time take input and assign it to the array. See below:

```
public static double[] dReadInputs(int numberOfInputs)       
    {
        int t = 0;
        double[] inputs = new double[numberOfInputs];
        while (t < numberOfInputs)
        {
            String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter value for grade " + (t + 1) + " : ");
            inputs[t] = Double.parseDouble(in);
            t++;
        }
        return inputs;
    }
```

You can also protect your code against possible **NullPointerException** which can happen when user do not provide input and close the input dialog using **Cancel** or **Close** buttons. Solution:

```
if (in != null) {
  //inform user to enter valid +ve integer/double
  //you might wanna continue back to loop without incrementing t 
}
```

You can protect the code against **NumberFormatException** by making sure that the user always inputs valid number and nothing else. Even empty input dialogue would cause exception: Solution:

```
try {
    inputs[t] = Double.parseDouble(in);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  //inform user to input valid +ve integer/double
  //you might wanna continue back to loop without incrementing t
}
```